# onCreateOptionsMenu hit multiples times with fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, android-menu

I have two ListFragments (A and B, which are actually `SherlockListFragments`) and when I put a breakpoint in the `onCreateOptionsMenu` in both fragments, Fragment A is hit 3 times and Fragment B is hit 2 times.  In addition, I am animating one of the menu icon when an `AsyncTask` is running and if I select an item in Fragment A, `onCreateOptionsMenu` is called again and the icon double up:

[image]

I'm not sure why `onCreateOptionsMenu` is called again because I'm just calling a method in the "details" fragment:

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(final ListView l, final View v, final int position, final long id)
{
    DetailsFragment fragment = (DetailsFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentDetails);

    if (fragment != null && fragment.isInLayout())
    {
        fragment.DisplayItems();
    } 
    else 
    {
        final Intent listing = new Intent(activity.getApplicationContext(), DetailsFragmentActivity.class);
        startActivity(listing);
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

I'm using this code to animate the menu item:

```
private MenuItem refreshItem;   

private void DoRefresh() 
{
    final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final ImageView ivRefresh = (ImageView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.refresh_view, null);

    final Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, R.anim.refresh);
    ImageView ivRefresh.startAnimation(rotation);

    refreshItem.setActionView(ivRefresh);

    //AsyncTask is kicked off here
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(final MenuItem item) 
{
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.refresh) {
        refreshItem = item;
        this.DoRefresh();
        return true;
    } else {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the documentation:

"After the system calls onCreateOptionsMenu(), it retains an instance of the Menu you populate and will not call onCreateOptionsMenu() again unless the menu is invalidated for some reason. However, you should use onCreateOptionsMenu() only to create the initial menu state and not to make changes during the activity lifecycle."

My guess is that the menu is being invalidated by something you are doing.  What does fragment.displayItems() do?

Comment: I added some code to my OP, which shows how I'm updating the menu items.  Not sure if this is invalidating the menu.  As far as what "DisplayItems" is doing, I don't have the code in front of me, but it's basically populating a custom adapter for a `ListView`.  Shouldn't be effecting the menu at all.

Comment: So, I'm an idiot and I had put in `invalidateOptionsMenu` in the "DisplayItems" function awhile ago and forgot to take it out, but I'll give you the credit for bring up invalidating the menu as a cause.